# How to insert a date value into an MDB database using VBScript?

Tags: ms-access, vbscript

I would like to know what I should do to insert some dates into a table. My table has 4 columns:

ID (AutoNumber)
First_Name
Last_Name
Date

I would like to insert some data with VBScript. Here is what I have so far:

```
sub DBinsert(fname, lname)
    Set objCon= CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set RS1 = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    WScript.echo "DBInsert"

    objCon.Open "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = C:\Users\bonhkarl01\Desktop\Blank database.mdb"



                    objCon.execute(" Insert into table3(First_Name, Last_Name, Date) Values ('" & fname & "','" & lname & "','" & Date() & "') ")


End sub
```

It worked so far when I tried without the "Date" in another table... Is there anything wrong with the `objCon.execute` command?

The error I am getting is

> Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Comment: Even with the exact same code as you provided, i have the issue. objCon.execute("Insert into table3(First_Name, Last_Name, Date) Values ('" & fname & "','" & lname & "',#" & Date() & "#);")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Date` is a [reserved word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248738) in Access SQL. If you need to refer to a column named `Date` then you must enclose it in square brackets.

```
objCon.execute(" Insert into table3 (First_Name, Last_Name, [Date]) Values ...
```